# Changing all Woocommerce Orders from "On-Hold" to "Complete"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm attempting to change all the orders on a Woocommerce store from "On Hold" to "Completed" Programatically. I could easilly do this in MySQL but unfortunately I need the woocommerce order complete triggers to take place to assign License Keys to the existing orders. I am doing this on a staging server with all emails disabled to save everyone some headaches.

So far I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work at all.

```html
function schedule_on_hold_complete() {
  if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'on_hold_complete' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'quarterly', 'on_hold_complete' );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_on_hold_complete' );


function on_hold_complete() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'wc-on-hold',
);

$orderList = get_posts($args);

foreach ($orderList as $orderPost) {
    $order = new WC_Order($orderPost->ID);
    $order->update_status('completed');
  }
}
add_action( 'on_hold_complete', 'on_hold_complete' );
```

I get no feedback at all from the above code. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Where and how are you initiating that code?

Comment: what happens if you var_dump($order) from your foreach?

Comment: @CKMacLeod, I currently have it set as a scheduled CRON Job in wp-crontrol, set so to monthly. I DO Have Cron enabled on the staging server, and when I run it, it claims to have run successfully, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @CKMacLeod, I will try to get some dumped info and update.

Comment: Since you're triggering this with the CRON... I would suggest you dump to error log `error_log(var_export($order));` and see what's coming out.  Make sure your $order object is being returned.

Comment: Is this something you want to happen once, to update your database, or to happen always - as in all orders are automatically set to "complete" status?

Comment: Hey Guys, I definitely had a brain fart. The issue was definitely that things were so large Cron was just saying "Yep, it's all good!" and then just kinda bailing on it when it timed out. Instead I re-set it up as a WP CLI Command and ran it that way, worked like a charm! The var_dump is super handy as well as it's giving me a decent live feed. So thank you everyone! This is solved! I will update my code to the code that worked for me going forward up top to help people going forward!

Answer (score 2):

After some consultation from the wonderful people here I was able to find the issue. Special thanks to @CKMacleod, @HowardE for jumpstarting my brain!

So, IF YOU NEED TO USE this to update run a batch (Like I am) or just to update a bunch of orders in a set, here is the code! Bear in mind, this will send out the "Order Complete" emails just like if you were doing it in the admin.

Note: I use WP-CLI to run the command, which I register at the end. "wp on_hold_complete". Also note, for a large site this is probably pretty inefficient, this code does cause the site to 500 via http but the CLI command works perfectly. Just make sure to echo something in the loop so you know it's running.

```html
/**
 * Change all on hold orders when action is triggered.
 */
function on_hold_complete() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'wc-on-hold',
);

$orderList = get_posts($args);

foreach ($orderList as $orderPost) {
    $order = new WC_Order($orderPost->ID);
    $order->update_status('completed');
  }
}
WP_CLI::add_command( 'on_hold_complete', 'on_hold_complete' );
```

Comment: Still kind of curious why you need to do this, since, if you just wanted to skip on-hold status - i.e., autocomplete orders - you could do that. Likewise if you wanted to trigger automatically in other ways, or just run on deman - but congrats for solving it on your own anyway: (Cron jobs are notoriously problematic for this kind of thing - could be host limits involved here, too.)

Comment: Basically, we added a license manager that assigns a unique key to each purchase on a per item basis, but does it in a weird way and also encrypts them in the database. So the easiest way was to move all the products into a staging server, set all completed to on hold via an SQL query and then re-process them after disabling all emails from the server, and yeah, we made sure our host knew what was up in advance so it was all good. Much better than manually bulk editing 160,000 orders.

Comment: I see... I think I would have tried a similar function to the one you've apparently successfully run with WP_CLI, but to each his own! Since I don't typically have WP_CLI set up, I usually run via shortcode, but I might look into your alternative at some point.